# Switch onclick not being called when switch is slid

Tags: android

I copied the code from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) pretty much verbatim. What I get looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diVnz.png).

It works when I quickly click the slider, ie, when I tap it slightly I get the expected result. However when I slide it from left to right by holding my finger down, nothing happens. The slider goes into the ON state but LocationClicked is never called. I Couldn't find an "onSlide" method, so I don't know what to do.

Do I have to use a listener for this or is there an easier way?

Part of the XML file:

```
<Switch
android:id="@+id/switch1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:text="@string/location_setting_string"
android:onClick="LocationClicked" />
```

Part of the Java code:

```
public void LocationClicked(View view) {
Log.i(TAG,"CLICK");
}
```

I'm running 4.4.2 on a Galaxy S5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I tap it slightly I get the expected result*

In this case the `onToggleClicked` event is fired.

*However when I slide it from left to right by holding my finger down, nothing happens.*

Thats because a slide gesture does not fire the `OnToggleClicked` event. (you are not clicking it)

To catch both you could use

```
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

This fires whenever the state of the toggle changed. It doesn't matter if you click it or slide, the state changes any way.